# Apache set-up with Flask and wsgi

Tags: python, linux, apache, wsgi

I have a small web application that I have built using Flask and python. With the internal server that I used for developing everything runs fine. However now I want to use apache to start using it. But it doesn`t work. Keep in mind that I have never worked with apache or web based stuff before.

I used this guide as my starting point:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/

right now I have my application which is in the file called "/rg/server.py" and looks like this:

```
app=Flask(__name__)
# all app routes...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        debug=True,
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port=80
    )
```

than I have a wsgi file as "/rg/wsgi/minerva.wsgi"

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, /rg)
from server import app as minerva
```

and finally I have an apache config file in "etc/apach2/sites-available/minerva.com":

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName minerva.test

    WSGIDaemonProcess minerva threads=10
    WSGIScriptAlias / /rg/wsgi/minerva.wsgi

    <Directory /rg>
    WSGIProcessGroup minerva
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Then I updated apache with a2ensite minerva.com which succeded. Then I releaded Apache and no errors. However I cannot acces minerva.test in any way...

If I type in apache2ctl -S it does list minerva.test

I have no idea what is going wrong...

system information:
OS: debian 64bit
python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSGI application entry point must be called 'application' for mod_wsgi. You have:

```
from server import app as minerva
```

It should be:

```
from server import app as application
```

You aren't even getting that far though, else the line:

```
sys.path.insert(0, /rg)
```

would give a syntax error.

Going back further, instead of:

```
<VirtualHost *>
```

you should have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

and finally, if 'minerva.test' isn't actually a resolvable host, you will not get anywhere.

So fill out your question with the actual URL you are using in the browser and also indicate whether 'minerva.test' is even listed in local hosts file.

Comment: Thank you. after doing what you said it works! only need to figure out how to allow clients in my lan to acces it via the minerva.test url :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check would be to make sure mod_wsgi is installed and loaded by apache. If that's fine, your setup looks pretty similar to mine with a few minor differences:

1. I had to add WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi above my VirtualHost definitoin. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationIssues).
2. I included user and group values on the WSGIDaemonProcess line.