# Flask, IIS, Python, wfastcgi Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'

Tags: python, flask, iis-10, wfastcgi

My problem is that I'm trying to deploy a simple flask **app.py** :

```python
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from FastCGI via IIS!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

with that **web.config**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
        <add name="Python FastCGI" path="*" verb="*" 
        modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python34\python.exe|C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
    resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
       </handlers>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
     </system.webServer>
     <appSettings>
       <!-- Required settings -->
       <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.app" />
       <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\Web\flaskapp" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

i get the error**Error:**

```txt
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 616, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))
ValueError: "app.app" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File ".\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'
```

He dont want import my libs(not all! he can improt time and other like this).

build:

```
wfastcgi-3.0.0-py3.4.egg-info
Flask-1.0.2.dist-info
python 3.4
IIS 10.0.14393
```

Big thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have a file called `flask.py`? Or `flask.pyc`?

Comment: no i dont.
but i put all libs to the app-folder and now i got new

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UsageError'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490897/flask-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-items

Comment: The WSGI application entry point must be called `application` for mod_wsgi. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24048455/4902099

Comment: 36h, four versions of python was installed, two wfastcgi. and I resolve my problem.  Goldkey is python 3.4.2 x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use python 3.4.2 x86 only.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to integrate flask into IIS.
python installation path was in "C:\Program files" folder and the error occurred because the path has a space (between Program and files).
I just reinstalled python on a directory without spaces (e. g. C:\Python_39) and everything worked fine.